# View pager content is not shown when we go from a drawer activity to that fragment?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, fragment, drawer

I have a view pager and it is showing content when it is in starting page but when we take that page from drawer activity it is not showing any content.Can anyone help me to solve out this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you set the fragment and FragmentPagerAdapter ?

you can follow this tutor for create viewpager: 
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

and this tutor link for combine drawer with viewpager
http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/05/android-basic-training-course-combining.html